# How to optimize index in Cosmos for complex query

Tags: indexing, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have quite complex - at least not basic - queries in Azure Cosmos, and I'm not sure my index strategy is the right one.

I have 3 types of queries:

Queries that group a count based on a truncate date in a defined period such as:

```sql
SELECT left(c.date,16) AS date,
       count(c.type) AS total
FROM c
WHERE c.liveID = @liveID
  AND c.type = @type
  AND (c.date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)
GROUP BY left(c.date,16)
```

Queries that group a count based on a truncate date in a defined period such as:

```sql
SELECT count(c.referrer) AS total,
       c.referrer
FROM c
WHERE c.type = "Load"
  AND c.liveID = @liveID
  AND c.referrer <> ''
  AND (c.date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)
```

Queries that do a count distinct (select into another select) and group a count based on a truncate date in a defined period such as:

```sql
SELECT a.date AS date,
       count(a.uuid) AS total
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT c.uuid,
                left(c.date, 16) AS date
FROM c
WHERE c.liveID = @liveId @type = 'Play'
  AND (c.date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) AS a
GROUP BY a.date
```

And below is my index policy:

```sql
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/liveID/?"
        },
        {
            "path": "/type/?"
        },
        {
            "path": "/date/?"
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        },
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ],
    "compositeIndexes": [
        [
            {
                "path": "/liveID",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/type",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/date",
                "order": "ascending"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Am I missing something to optimize those queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Index policies defined look right as you have two equality filters (LiveID and type) and one range filter(date), so defining a single composite index on all three properties makes sense. As per the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#composite-indexes) as well this is the way to define indexes, please refer to below screenshot from the doc

[image]

However, in one of your query you are using another filter expression 'referrer ', this can also be added based on it usage accordingly.